# Using VBA in Outlook, how can I convert an Excel range to a table?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to convert an Excel range to a table using a VBA script run from Outlook.

This worked when run from Excel but not from Outlook:

```
ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:D10"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"
```

I tried this next code in Outlook but it failed:

```
Dim excApp As Excel.Application
Set excApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")    
excApp.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1:D10"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"
```

This code threw run-time error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.

I want to know how to make the code work, but I also want to understand why my code failed so that I can learn from it.  I appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in Excel you already have a sheet open. The ActiveSheet is the default when you just stick `Range("somerange")` without specifying which sheet, workbook, or excel application object that range exists in. In outlook there is no such thing as `activesheet` and so it has no idea what you mean by that range.

You'll have to be more explicit:

```
Dim excApp As Excel.Application
Set excApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")  
Dim excWB as Object
Set excWB = excApp.Workbooks.Add  
excApp.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, excWB.sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:D10"), , xlYes).Name = "myTable"
```

Or something along those lines

In short, an excel application has workbooks, workbooks have sheets, and sheets have ranges.